# Subclassing Android Application in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have custom Application class in my Android project that is properly described in manifest and actually works.

But one small question: do I really need to call in this way methods implemented in my `App` class:

`((App) getApplication()).callSomeMethod();`

because IDEA doesn't allow me to run application:

`cannot find symbol method callSomeMethod()`

or I can avoid it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** typecast the result from `getApplication()` to your subclass. This isn't anything Android specific, but rather, how the Java language works.

Comment: Yep, thanks. Found solution for me: I have BaseActivity in wich I implemented method for retrieving application with typecast.